# registros duplicados de una consulta

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy realizando una consulta para buscar todos aquellos productos que no estén relacionados a una tabla llamada Stock donde el campo "Ruta" dentro de la tabla Stock sea diferente del id que estoy pasando por el Url. lo estoy realizando de la siguiente manera:

```
@productos = Producto.joins('left outer join stock on productos.Clave=stock.Articulo')
                     .select('productos.*,stock.Articulo')
                     .where('stock.ruta != ? AND productos.Status = ?', params[:id], "A")
```

El problema con esta consulta es que me esta mostrando los productos repetidos, dependiendo la cantidad de stocks a los que esta asociado dicho producto, ¿Como podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías intentar llamando al método `distinct`, algo como esto:

```
@productos = Producto.joins('left outer join stock on productos.Clave=stock.Articulo')
                 .select('productos.*,stock.Articulo')
                 .where('stock.ruta != ? AND productos.Status = ?', params[:id], "A")
                 .distinct
```

Comment: gracias @Monpeco, funciono pero ahora tengo un pequeño problema y es que estoy buscando aquellos registros que no esten asociados al stock donde el campo ruta sea diferente del id que estoy pasando como parametro. cuando el producto no esta asociado al stock y creo un stock asociado al producto, este no me lo trae la consulta y es justo lo que quiero pero si el producto ya esta asociado a otro stock, asi lo tenga asociado al stock con la ruta id de parametro, me lo sigue trayendo debido a que otro stock con otra ruta id lo tiene

Comment: Perfecto @LuisC, si la respuesta te funcionó por favor marca la respuesta como aceptada por favor. Y en cuanto al otro tema, deberías de crear otra pregunta, y ahí vemos todos como te podemos ayudar. Saludos.

Comment: ok ya la publico